# Access mongoid config variables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, environment-variables

I'm writing some rspec tests to make sure that the mongoid variables are assigned correctly as they changed about half way through development before one of us caught it.

Not 100% sure how to access them though. If i was in production then I could just use the ENV variables

```
uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

And other ENV vars. But for testing and development, how do i access them?

Answer (score 1):

ENV is a hash-like accessor for environment variables (system variables). 
You can access and define(override) them in testing and development.

```
ENV["LOL"]='lol'
ENV["LOL"]
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that the mongoid vars dont exist in test a dev on the local machines. The ENV vars for mongoig are already set for heroku and other rails deployment things.

Comment: u can add them to your local env vars in shell `export $MONGO_PASS="ffff"` or add it in `~/.environment_pam` file or just define them in initializer `ENV["LOL"]='lol' if Rails.env != 'production'`